# Can I restrict a type to values of an Interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Here is what I want:

```
interface ValidValues {
  TOP: number;
  BOTTOM: number;
}

function f(b: valuesof(ValidValues)) {
}

function g(valid: ValidValues) {
  f(valid.TOP);
  f(3); // should not compile
}
```

Even though it's not impossible that 3 happens to equal valid.TOP or valid.BOTTOM, since it cannot be demonstrated at compile-time, I want it to err out.

Possible?

Yes, I know nothing stops a user from constructing his own implementation of ValidValues with TOP or BOTTOM set to 3.  I am in this situation where a Javascript library is giving my a function *and* giving me a object full of values to call it with, and I'm trying to type it in Typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want something like [branded primitives](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) to have a type `ValidValue` which is assignable *to* `number` but is not assignable *from* `number`.  This is a trick where you intersect `number` with an object type containing a "brand" property so the compiler can tell the difference between a plain `number` and a branded `ValidValue`, even though at runtime there is no difference (a `ValidValue` will not really have the brand property at runtime).

Something like this:

```
type ValidValue = number & { __brand: "ValidValue" };

interface ValidValueObj {
  TOP: ValidValue;
  BOTTOM: ValidValue;
}
```

Let's see how it works:

```
function f(b: ValidValue) {}

function g(valid: ValidValueObj) {
  f(valid.TOP);
  f(3); // error as desired
}
```

And if you want to force the compiler to accept a `number` as `ValidValue` you can use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function getValidValueObj(top: number, bot: number): ValidValueObj {
    return {
        TOP: top as ValidValue,
        BOTTOM: bot as ValidValue
    }; 
}
```

Does that help?  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBN4IK7QLxQHYYC2ARhAE5QBkUA3lAPr3Flx4oBcUAROqullygBfANwAoMUjzByAMzgBjaLzSIsAeWIArWmKhQAKuoAKnFfwjj9AIXUGjAWTOI+ay2KETZGPAuBIAezwoWQAKYmdkVUwIAEpaTzFvX38gqABzUIA3Fw5YXItNLXiaPRDs3IA6I2NYq3KAZjqoAHoWqHIyAIo4AGcoFAhepDIIFA8JNqgAVV7oUEgoPrmyVLx+4AClvwxEBBAoQjgAa2g4fKiLJJ8-QOD0iGBzNyLQzbBOAhJyABooYgCwE+RFIZFikVcMSKun0+lGwAwZGCpVhqMMJk47yW-WeMR+ZTRUFs9nUTn+gOxF0hWAJwg8QA)

Answer (score 0):

> Possible

No. Not with the interface:

```
interface ValidValues {
  TOP: number;
  BOTTOM: number;
}
```

Anything that accepts values from `ValidValues` will accept any `number` (like `3`)